# Android: Firebase taking too much time to fetch data

Tags: java, android, arraylist, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Realtime database feature of Firebase in my Application. Database looks like this:
[image: database snap]

The nodes 104, 1040... are having further elements/data. I'm fetching this data ordering it by value at a node 'updatedAt' available within every Integer parent as shown in the snap. I am using `onChildAddedListener()` to fetch the last 20 elements. There are around 1050 nodes within 'results'.

The problem:

1. The fetching of data takes too much time, around 30 sec, even on high speed WiFi.
2. Does Firebase allows any callback to notify that data has been fetched? I want to append every custom object to the `ArrayList` received from Firebase and pass it through intent to another activity. I am counting the objects received and when it becomes 20, I open up my Activity. Is that the only way to do so? If there is some better way out, do suggest.

Here is my code:

```
 public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity{

        private static final String TAG = "Splash Activity";
        private ArrayList<News> NewsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();   
        private DatabaseReference newsReference;
        private int position = 0;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

            newsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("results");
            Query queryNewsReference = newsReference.orderByChild("updatedAt").limitToLast(20);
            fetchNews(queryNewsReference);
        }

        private void fetchNews(Query queryNewsReference) {

            queryNewsReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    News newsObject = dataSnapshot.getValue(News.class);
                    Log.d(TAG,"News Title: "+ newsObject.getVideo_title());
                    NewsArrayList.add(newsObject);
                    position++;
                    if(position == 20){
                    startMainActivity(); 
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged() called on key: "+ dataSnapshot.getKey());
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChildRemoved() called on key: "+ dataSnapshot.getKey());
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved() called on key: "+ dataSnapshot.getKey());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Database Error: "+databaseError.toString());
                }
            });
        }

        private void startMainActivity() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("NewsList",NewsArrayList);
            Splash.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Does the 30 second delay occur before you see the first "onChildAdded" logcat message? Once you see the first "onChildAdded", do the others follow immediately?

Comment: @qbix Yes. 30sec delay is before I see first 'onChildAdded'. BTW what is the difference? If onChildAdded() is called then it means data has been fetched, right?

Comment: Just looking for clues.  FWIW I created a test case very similar to yours (1100 objects, ordered by child, limited to last 20) and don't see the delays.  I'm in California--maybe better connection to the servers than you.

Comment: @qbix: I see. 
Apart from this, about my second point in the question. Is that the right way to do? Or if there is a better way, do suggest.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen Being an engineer at Firebase, it would be great if you can provide your insights. Thanks!

Comment: I'm also facing the issue on lowend weak device

Answer (score 1):

Try reconnecting to firebase before adding value listener:

```
private void fetchNews(Query queryNewsReference) 
{    
    if (FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() != null)
    {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();
    }

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline();

    queryNewsReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

    ...
}
```